# Modem Over IP or VOIP?

Tags: sip, voip, modem

I need to connect to a remote server via a modem for a legacy app. I don’t have physical access to my server so adding a real modem isn't an option.

Does anyone know of:

1. A service that provides Modem Over IP? Something like Twilio, but just for modems.
2. A modem / SIP client that would allow me to emulate a modem on a specific COM port that connects to a VOIP provider?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I see quite a few people with this problem, but no great solutions.

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: You can add software modem

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [PPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) (or maybe [PPPoE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol_over_Ethernet)).  PPP is very common and is still used heavily today pretty much everywhere you have a home connected internet connection.

You need to look at whatever OS you are using and see what they provide to be able connect two computers via a modem and create a TCP/IP connection between them.  That way you don't need to change your program, as it will showup as a network connection.

Under windows you have this for accepting [incoming connections](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753616%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).